# limited the input of date to specific range in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, date, input, calendar

I have a list of different dates, in this format YYYYMMDD. and I have an input field type date as below, HTML and Javascript. I used a method by Jquery datePicker but I have not reached a solution yet. I prefer to use standard HTML and Javascript.

```
<input type="date" id="selDate" placeholder="e.g. 20180925">
```

My question is that I want to update this input date calender and highlighted multiple days based on the different date given so the user will be allowed to pick days within the given list of date.

so based on the below dates example, the user should only able to pickup those dates.

20180510
20161209

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use min, max parameters to limit the selectable range of dates:

```html
<input type="date" id="selectedDate" min="2016-12-09" max="2018-05-10">
```

You can also "replace" the date picker with a list:

```html
<input type="date" id="selectedDate" name="date" list="datesList">

<datalist id="datesList">
    <option label="Day one">2016-12-09</option>
    <option label="Day two">2018-05-10</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Thank you Piotr for the giving idea, but what I want exactly is that when users click on the calendar icon, they will see only the selectable days based on the limited list given, and the other days should be in grey colour which is not selectable, so users will not be allowed to click them. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To make the input fields change dynamically as time passes:
Here I want to make the user choose one day from the month we are currently at. Then set the values of the first and last day as an input date field attribute: min and max.

```js
// Limit the date input fields to the current days of the month we are currently in
const today = new Date();

// Get Last day of the month
const lastDay = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 1); // => Date Fri Apr 1 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)

// Format the last day to a string so the it could be used as max value for input date field
const maxDate = lastDay.toISOString().slice(0, 10); // 2023-3-31
// Get first day of the month
const firstDay = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 1); // Date Wed Mar 01 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)

// Format the first day to a string so the it could be used as min value for input date field
const minDate = firstDay.toISOString().slice(0, 10);

// Loop through eaxh date input field and add the max min attributes
document.querySelectorAll("input[type='date']").forEach((input) => {
    input.setAttribute('max', maxDate);
    input.setAttribute('min', minDate);
});
```